# LINQ query, ignoring results with certain decimal points

Tags: c#, linq, double, where-clause, decimal-point

I need to perform a LINQ query on a large database in C#. One of the columns I need to use in the query is a double. I need to omit results that have more than 4 decimal places in this column. The database can't be changed as other programs need to use it and make use of what I don't want. The results are then added to a list to use later. I thought that this would work.

```
where fun.Units != '*.?????*'
```

However it returns the error that too many characters are in the character literal.
The whole query looks like this so far

```
var clientQuery1 = from cli in main1.Clients
                   from pol in main1.Policies
                   from fun in main1.FundHoldings
                   from uni in main1.UnitPrices
                   where cli.AccountNumber == accNum
                   && pol.ClientRef == cli.ClientRef
                   && fun.FKeyRef == pol.PolicyRef
                   && uni.UnitPriceRef == fun.UnitPriceRef
                   && fun.Units != '*.?????*'
                   select uni.UnitName;
```

Comment: Made a mistake in my post, it's not a decimal it's a double

Comment: @Stuart: In that case it's not really meaningful to talk about how many *decimal* figures it's got. For example, the closest double to "0.1" has *lots* of digits when you represent it exactly in decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with this below query and let me know.

```
var clientQuery1 = from cli in main1.Clients
                   from pol in main1.Policies
                   from fun in main1.FundHoldings
                   from uni in main1.UnitPrices
                   where cli.AccountNumber == accNum
                   && pol.ClientRef == cli.ClientRef
                   && fun.FKeyRef == pol.PolicyRef
                   && uni.UnitPriceRef == fun.UnitPriceRef
                   && fun.Units == Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(fun.Units),4)
                   select uni.UnitName;
```

Comment: Getting the error that the best overloaded method match has invalid arguements for the part Math.Round(fun.Units,4)

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I changed (Convert.ToDouble(fun.Units),4) to (fun.Units.Value,4) as it is already a double (made a mistake in the original post). Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can solve *that particular* error using:

```
&& fun.Units != "*.?????*"
```

Note the change from single quotes to double quotes. However, that's not going to help you overall. What's the type of `fun.Units` in LINQ? If it's decimal, you *might* be able to use:

```
&& decimal.Round(fun.Units, 4) == fun.Units
```

... but it's not clear to me what that will do in the generated SQL. It's worth a try, but even if it works you should see what the SQL looks like.

Comment: I suspect that the round won't work as i think SQL will implicitly cast both operands in something list WHERE CAST(units as Decimal (18,4)) = units to Decimal (18,4)

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that's a distinct possibility. It's the best suggestion I've got at a moment...

Comment: I was wrong it does work, i tried `SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE CAST(Value as Decimal(18,1)) <> Value` where Value field is of type Decimal(18,2) on a SQL 2008 R2 database and it did return rows.